# MetaMask not prompting for transaction when calling method with ethjs

Tags: transactions, metamask, ethjs

I am trying to interact with a contract that i've created on Rinkeby (0xff1175c8030083dbf211bf6e2e1e7e1182a8f8bb)

I have my provider detected, wrapped with ethjs. When I try to read the contract, there is no problem the values are returned. When I try to write the contract, MetaMask (which is enabled and shows a connected account, with ethereum on it) does not as to validate the transaction.

contract abi (short version)

```json
[{
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "getSchema",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function",
      "constant": true
    },
{
      "inputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "_schema",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "name": "setSchema",
      "outputs": [],
      "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
      "type": "function"
    },
]
```

usage

```js
import detectEthereumProvider from '@metamask/detect-provider';

async function main() {
    let plugin_provider = await detectEthereumProvider();

    if ('function' === typeof plugin_provider.enable) {
        await plugin_provider.enable();
    }

    const provider = new window.Eth(plugin_provider);
    const contract = await provider.contract(abi).at('0xff1175c8030083dbf211bf6e2e1e7e1182a8f8bb');

    let result = await contract.getSchema();
    console.log(result); // Object { 0: "https://schema.org/Person" }

    result = await contract.setSchema(result[0] + 'Modified', { from: app.account });
    console.log(result); // Object { }

    result = await contract.getSchema();
    console.log(result); // Object { 0: "https://schema.org/Person" }
}

main();
```

The contract "connection" is working, as the result of `getSchema` is the one expected. I can't understand why `setSchema` is not making MetaMask asking to sign the transaction. Am I doing something wrong? I would expect MetaMask to prompt to sign the transaction since it is not a view.

Comment: Assuming that your account is unlocked on the node: `await contract.setSchema(...).send({from: yourAccountAddress})`.

Comment: @goodvibration iirc ethjs contract should actually do that under the hood when it recognized that a method is not a view (=> doing a .send on setSchema throws an error)

Comment: I'm having the same problem... did you ever work out how to fix this?